# RxJava; How to emit observables synchronously

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to synchronously emit two Observable objects (which are asynchronous), one after the other where it returns the *first* emitted Observable object. If the first one fails, it should not emit the second one.

Let's say we have one Observable that signs a user in, and another Observable that automatically selects the user's account, *after* signing in.

This is what I tried:

```
public Observable<AccessToken> signInAndSelectAccount(String username, String password)
{

    Observable<AccessToken> ob1 = ...; // Sign in.
    Observable<Account> ob2 = ...; // Select account.


    return Observable.zip(
            ob1,
            ob2,
            new Func2<AccessToken, Account, AccessToken>() {
                @Override
                public AccessToken call(AccessToken accessToken, Account account)
                {
                     return accessToken;
                }
            });
}
```

This unfortunately does not work for my use case. It will emit/call both observables parallel, starting with 'ob1'.

Did someone encounter a similar use case? Or has an idea on how to make observables wait for eachother in a synchronous way, where the first emitted can be returned?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such term as "wait" in reactive programming. You need to think about creating of a data stream, where one `Observable` could be triggered by another. In your case after receiving `token` you need to receive `account`. It could look like this:

```
Observable<Account> accountObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<AccessToken>() {
    @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super AccessToken> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onNext(new AccessToken());
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
}).flatMap(accessToken -> Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Account>() {
    @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Account> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onNext(new Account(accessToken));
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
}));
```

Comment: This is not correct. While it is true that you should avoid blocking calls under most circumstances, RxJava 1 provides `BlockingObservable` and RxJava 2 provides several `.blocking*()` methods to interface with legacy code that is non-reactive.

Comment: Really basic example of where youd need to wait: you call this at the end of a unit test, maybe there is some pattern for this, but it sure isn't obvious

Answer (score 8):

You can also use rx.observables.BlockingObservable e.g.:

```
BlockingObservable.from(/**/).single();
```

Comment: `BlockingSingle.from(/**/)` is also an option, specifically for `Single`.

Comment: But how do you handle onError?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Single.blockingGet](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#blockingGet--) for synchronous call

```
// example 
signIn(name,password).blockingGet()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Java, but the solution in Scala would probably be this, hope it is readable to you

```scala
import rx.lang.scala.Observable

class AccessToken
class Account

case class TokenAndAccount(token: AccessToken, account: Account)

val accessTokenSource = Observable.just(new AccessToken)
val accountSource = Observable.just(new Account)

accessTokenSource
   .flatMap(token ⇒ accountSource.map(account ⇒ TokenAndAccount(token, account)))
   .subscribe(tokenAndAccount ⇒ println(tokenAndAccount))
```

Basically `flatMap` will make sure that the `accountSource.map...` is used only after the token from `accessTokenSource` has been emitted. Inside the `accountSource.map` we combine the obtained token and account together for later usage in `subscribe`.

`flatMap` is one of the most useful operators, be sure to read it's docs and perhaps some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Also, we can use `.toBlocking()` method in `Observable` which will make as **`BlockingObservable`**. i.e.,

`Observable.just().toBlocking();`