# want to return a value and process order is something wrong

Tags: android, rx-java

I need to return a value from Method C in Class B.

I want my code to be processed like : 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5

but it's processed like : 1 - 4 - 5 - 2 - 3

(As you can see, I put some logs in the code.)

I've been working with this problem over a week but I couldn't find the problem.

I removed some useless code in this question.

What is the problem and how can I figure this problem out?

I rewrite the post because someone said I shortened the code too much.

Hope it is enough!

Thank you in advance!

---

```
Class A
public class a() {
    public void checkConnectivity(Context context) {
         this.context = context;
         myObservable.subscribe(mySubscriber);
    }

    private Observable<Integer> myObservable = Observable.create(
        new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> sub) {
                Log.d("1", "1");
                int connType = cc.getConnectionStatus(context);
                sub.onNext(connType);
                sub.onCompleted();
            }
        }
    );

    private Subscriber<Integer> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer connType) {
            int code = c.getcode();
            Log.d("4", "4");
            textView.setText("code : " + code);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d("5", "5");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d("-- NetPresenter", "onError");
        }
    };
}

Class C
public class C() {
    public int getcode() {
         observable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("3", "3");
                }

                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    code = 0;
                }

                public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    code = 1;
                    Log.d("2", "2");
                }
            });
        return code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your running on new threads all the time, it depends which thread finishes first, it's asyncronous.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is running on new threads all the time inefficient? What would you recommend?

Comment: I'm saying rx-java is asyncronous by nature. Running on new threads all the time is fine but is also asyncronous, if you need them ordered (syncronous), you have to do it differently.

Comment: See     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062485/rxjava-how-to-emit-observables-synchronously

Comment: Thank you for your kindness Jon. I changed my code synchronously but it works same.. weird haha..

Comment: I'll look at your code in the morning, sleep well.

Comment: Where do you use your mySubscriber? There is only its declaration.

Comment: Hello maxost. Actually there's another method which uses myObservable.subscribe(mySubscriber) in Class A. I think the problem is about async. I'm totally new to android, especially Async so I'm still finding a way

Comment: You need to provide the full code in order that we understand it.

Comment: Hi Hans, I can provide the full code but only thing different is class A. I added the code for you

Comment: checkConnectivity is called when the button's clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all RxJava *is synchronous* by default if nothing else specified. 
These two lines

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

make your `c.getcode()` call asynchronous. If you remove these lines, you'll get what you need. I checked it by myself.

P.S. Please note that `textView.setText("code : " + code);` could throw exception (if you initiate whole chain not from UI thread). So you need to find workaround to run this code in UI thread (Handler with Looper.getMainLooper() could help).

**Upd 1.** try `postById.execute()` to run request in the same thread. You can achieve your goal if and only if you make all calls in the same thread. `postById.enqueue` initialize async call. So you broke it again.

Comment: Thank you Stas. Unfortunately I removed whole observable code but it was same. I coded like `postById.enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {`

Comment: I use code that you provided with question and everything works for me. You could even try it be yourself from this project, where I keep some interesting code: https://github.com/Shakenbeer/articles.
So I believe I've answered your initial question.

Could you please provide current code so we could figure it out?